# PHP/Javascript returning json object's that can only be queried by character

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to use the highcharts.js library and in doing so I am trying to return data from a php file. I believe my php file is correct but here is the code(Config.php gives me the conneciton to my mySQL database):

```
<?php

function fetch_data()
{
    include("Config.php");


    $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dataTable");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
    {
        $value = $row['dataValue'];
        $timestamp = $row['dateValue'];
        $data[] = ["date"=>$timestamp, "dataValue"=>(int)$value];
    }
     return json_encode($data);

}

echo fetch_data();
?>
```

I am using the `$.get` function to retrieve the data and place them into arrays that I can access, I have put in comments what has and has not worked. I've used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) before, but it is not working in this case & I cannot figure out why. Here is the js code embedded in an html file:

```
$(function() {

$.get('/fetch.php', function(data) {
    //returns all the json objects
    alert(data);

    //this function does not store any value in theDate or numSteps
    /*
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), funciton(k, v) {
        if (k === 'date')
        {
            theDate.push(v);
        }
        if (k === 'dataValue')
        {
            numSteps.push(v);
        }
    });
    */
    //returns 'undefined'
    alert(data.date);
    //returns [
    alert(data[0]);
    //returns {
    alert(data[1]);
    //returns "
    alert(data[2]);
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //alert(data);
        $('#container').highcharts({

        title : {
            text : 'Data'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Data',
            data : data
        }]
    });
    });

});

});
```

Here is a snippet of the output of fetch.php:

```
[{"date":"2015-12-03","dataValue":2449},{"date":"2015-12-04","dataValue":2528}]
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `data[0].date` and `data[0].dataValue` in other words you need to write a loop to process the array of objects you are returning

Comment: `$.get` will take an inteligent guess that you are returning JSON so you should not need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: 'data[0].date' also returns undefined. I'm not sure how I can write the function to loop throuh all the entries when i have thousands of entries. is there any other way i can receive this data from my php file and insert the data into an array variable in my javascript?

Comment: The data returned as JSON is an javascript array, or at least it shoudl be. Have you looked at the data using the browsers javascript debugger

Comment: Yes I have.. it is the same as it would be for the alerts. I do however get an error that says "client.js:110 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ client.js:110"...not really sure what that means though and have googled it.

Comment: Probably, it means that you did not include jquery. As was mentioned, you have to process your data, you can do this in the browser or on the server.